# Log in to Goodreads with another service

Tags: login, facebook-integration, goodreads

I am using the [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/) service, I used to login using my Facebook account.

I did a lot of activities on Goodreads previously, I recently deactivated my Facebook account which means I cannot log in to Goodreads.

My question is, if I want to login to Goodreads using another service such as Google or Twitter, is there any provision to restore the activities which I have previously done using the login with Facebook?

Comment: You'll probably have to contact Goodreads for help. You could have associated an email and password with your Goodreads account before  deactivating your Facebook account. This would have given you the option to login without Facebook and keep all your data. http://www.goodreads.com/help/show/133-can-i-sign-into-the-goodreads-ios-app-with-my-twitter-or-facebook-or-gma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Goodreads guys, from their [Contact Us](http://www.goodreads.com/about/contact_us) page as told by  @tinym in commenrs

With few email exchanges with them i got my Goodreads account back.